# How is data loaded from local content in a WebView embedded in a UWP app?

Tags: javascript, windows, webview, uwp

Given a WebView in a UWP app and a HTML page is loaded into the WebView from the local content via the `ms-appx-web://` protocol. How can JavaScript in that HTML also load data from the same location.

E.g.

We have the following files in `/Assets/`

`Foo.html`

`init.js`

`data.dat`

The WebView has it's `Source` set to `Source="ms-appx-web:///Assets/Foo.html"`
In `Foo.html` there is the tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script>`

In `init.js` I try the following but I get a response `500`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("GET", "ms-appx-web:///Assets/data.dat", true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function xhr_onload() {
    if (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0 && xhr.response) {
        // Never get a successful response
    } else {
        // I'm getting xhr.status === 500
    }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
xhr.send(null)
```

Comment: change your `src` to `src="ms-appx-web:///Assets/init.js"`

Comment: AVK, can you explain to me or point me at some documentation why that's necessary?

Additionally I also found that sometimes, for example within a promise, I need to use the app's guid as a hostname or I'll get a 500 too. E.g. `ms-apps-web://d52c0ce5-93ae-47df-a5f7-8faf0865615e/Assets/somefile.dat`